# Is it possible to specify both range and header in Scilab's csvRead?

Tags: scilab

The Scilab documentation for [csvRead](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/csvRead.html) indicates that it is possible to both specify a range (from row,col to row,col) and the number of header rows to ignore.  However I can only seem to do one at a time.

This is what I am doing (based on one of the examples in the documentation; using Scilab 5.5.0).  First, create a CSV file to read back:

```
    CSV = ["1,0,0,0,0"; 
    "0,1,0,0,0";
    "0,0,1,0,0"; 
    "4,4,1,2,0"; 
    "4,63,1,2,0";
    "4,63,1,4,233";
    "42,3,23,2,23";
    ];
    filename = fullfile(TMPDIR , 'foo.csv');
    mputl(CSV, filename);
```

Now read back the data from row 2, col 1 to row 5, col 4:

```
    csvRead(filename, [], [], "double", [], [], [2 1 5 4])
```

This gives the result

```
    ans  =

    0.    1.     0.    0.  
    0.    0.     1.    0.  
    4.    4.     1.    2.  
    4.    63.    1.    2.
```

Now suppose I want to skip the first line in my CSV file (it might have some unimportant header information in it).  I would write:

```
    csvRead(filename, [], [], "double", [], [], [], 1)
```

Which gives the result

```
    ans  =

    0.     1.     0.     0.    0.    
    0.     0.     1.     0.    0.    
    4.     4.     1.     2.    0.    
    4.     63.    1.     2.    0.    
    4.     63.    1.     4.    233.  
    42.    3.     23.    2.    23.
```

All good so far.  If I want to skip the first line AND only store part of the matrix, I presumed I could write:

```
    csvRead(filename, [], [], "double", [], [], [2 1 5 4], 1)
```

But this gives the same answer as before, i.e. only the header line is removed and the range is ignored:

```
    ans  =

    0.     1.     0.     0.    0.    
    0.     0.     1.     0.    0.    
    4.     4.     1.     2.    0.    
    4.     63.    1.     2.    0.    
    4.     63.    1.     4.    233.  
    42.    3.     23.    2.    23.
```

Is it possible to specify both a range and a header?  I only tinker with Scilab so may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's a bug in scilab, because if I look in the source I see, that the 7th parameter (range) is not evaluated, if 8th parameter (header) is given.
It's a simple bug caused by wrong comparison operator (== instead of >=).

Comment: I was going to add this on the Scilab issue tracker but you (I presume!) beat me to it, thanks for the confirmation.